# How can I paint a clover in Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, awt

I just wanted to know if anyone knows how to paint a four-leaf clover in java, using java swing and java awt. I only know how to do fillRect() or drawRec() and other built-in java methods. However, I don't know how to make shapes that look like the leaves in the clover or the stem. If anyone knows how to draw or paint one in java using swing and awt, please let me know, and thanks.

Comment: DYM [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVWp7.png)? That's a simple [mathematical formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrifolium).

Comment: yea that shape, but how can I implement that into java swing or awt?

Comment: *"how can I implement that into java swing or awt?"* By translating that formula into x,y co-ordinates. (Is how I made that curve.) The thing is, this question has an accepted answer. If it's not solved, why is the answer accepted?

Comment: Assuming you need to draw a four-leaf clover, it's four heart shapes and a stem.  The stem can be a thick straight line.  A heart is two half circles with the outside points connected in a triangle shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Create a Shape for your clover and use Graphics2D.draw/.fill(Shape) to draw your clovers. You might want to check out the geom.[Area](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html) class for this.
2. (Recommended) Find an image of a clover icon with a transparent background

In either case, once you have your clover "stamp", it is just a matter of translating and rotating the graphics2D to paste your stamp where you want it.

Comment: im not sure if my teacher will allow this but I will ask. Thank you for the solution!

Comment: is it fine if you can give me an example of I can use the graphics2d.draw/.fill to create a leaf of a clover?

Comment: I really don't know how your create a leaf of a clover. But as far as dealing with Areas (and polygons) I created a package years ago you might want to check out: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/shape/